# How to take identificator from html button

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have that form in index.html

```
<form action="Servlet">
    <p>Type text:<br><textarea cols="100" rows="10" name=encipher></textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Encipher" name=encipherSubmit id="a"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Decipher" name=decipherSubmit id="b"/>
    </form>
```

And i dont't know how to get some identificator from buttons. I need to execute encipher method when 1st button pushed and decipher method when 2nd button pushed.
For textarea in Servlet.java i have code:

```
String encipher = req.getParameter("encipher");
```

And how to take parameter from buttons ?

Comment: Address it by the name you give it like any other input and use some logic on that...ie if encipher...then encrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every input is sent using the name that you gave it. Your submit buttons have names. So, if you click the "Encipher" button, you will have a parameter called `encipherSubmit` whose value is `Encipher`. If you clicked the "Decipher" button, you'll have a parameter called `decipherSubmit` whose value is `Decipher`.

It's just as if these were text fields, but the good thing is that only the button which you actually used for submission will be sent.

So you can do something like:

```
String encipherButton = req.getParameter("encipherSubmit");
String decipherButton = req.getParameter("decipherSubmit");

if ( encipherButton != null && encipherButton.equals("Encipher") ) {

    // Do encipher operation

} else if ( decipherButton != null && decipherButton.equals("Decipher") ) {

    // Do decipher operation

} else {

    // Form was submitted without using the buttons.
    // Decide what you want to do in this case.
}
```

In fact, in most cases, just checking `encipherButton != null` and `decipherButton != null` is sufficient.

Comment: In fact, you're better off not checking the value as per my comment on @Pshemo's answer - the null check is better by itself

Comment: Since I removed my answer comment mentioned by @CupawnTae also disappeared so I will try to simplify it: `if (encipherButton != null)` is enough because regardless of what value will be shown in browser like `"Encipher"`, `"encipher"`, or maybe even `"encrypt"` we already know that it was submit button with name `encipherSubmit` which was clicked. This simplified condition allows us to use any `value` which is nice for internationalization. What matters is that `name` will always be the same.

Comment: The basic point was that it's a bad idea to rely on the displayed text - you should use an independent and fixed identifier (i.e. the button name in this case). The displayed text could change at any time (internationalization being a very common example) and if you're testing for a specific value, the code will then break.

Answer (score -2):

Well you can't know which button you click this way, because buttons just do the form submit. Actually servlet can process any header or data you send via HTTP, but button name is not send.

Alternatively you can write a javascript onclick event handler for each button and then send the submit programmaticly with additional parameter - the button clicked.

Comment: The name and value are sent when you submit the HTML form.